# Convert SVG to PNG/JPEG not working on FF

Tags: reactjs, image, svg, firefox

I have a problem with my script which find a svg in the dom and get the svg downloaded as jpeg or png. Everything works fine on chrome but on firefox i download an empty image. Can you help me ?

this is my script

```
   const downloadImage = () =>{
    // Find the svg by ref
    const selectedSvg = chartRef.current
    const svgSizes = selectedSvg.getBBox()
    const width = svgSizes.width * scale
    const height = svgSizes.height * scale
    // Create a Blob of the svg
    const clonedSvgElement = selectedSvg.cloneNode(true);
    const xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(clonedSvgElement);
    const blob = new Blob([xml],{type:'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
    const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
    const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // Create a canvas for drawing the new img
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    debugger;
    
   
    const image = new Image();
    // Add the img into the canvas and download it
    image.onload = () => { 
      canvas.width = width
      canvas.height = height    
      context.fillStyle = backgroundColor ?? "transparent";
      context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
    
      const imgUri = canvas.toDataURL(type, compression);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.download = fileName;
      link.href = imgUri;
      link.click();
    };

    image.src = blobURL;

  }
```

Comment: Does selectedSvg (i.e. the SVG you're trying to draw have height and width attributes on its root <svg> element and if it does are those percentages or not. Firefox requires them to exist and not be percentages.

Comment: Hello no the svg has only viewbox attr

Comment: I am not sure.. haven't done much with this.. but by my notes you need ``image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';``

Comment: Ok i tried to add with and height on svg container and it's working now.. Thanks a lot